# Is there a quicker way of accomplishing this without doing it manually in Excel

Tags: excel

What I'm trying to accomplish here is make duplicates of every row in my file and add on to the cell. For an example I have this:

```
productID    size1  size2 size3 size4 size5       Amount
1             5      6     7     8     9           210
2             4      6     8     10    11          246
3             5      8     11    12    13          180
4             6      7     8      9    10          175
5             1      2     3      4     5          450
```

What I need to do is this:

```
productID  size   Amount
1           5        210
1           6        210
1           7        210
1           8        210
1           9        210
2           4        246
2           6        246
2           8        246
2           10       246
2           11       246
3            5       180
```

and so on
Is there a quicker way of accomplishing this without doing it manually. I have a maximum of 4000 products with 8 different sizes.Need your help

Comment: is it always 5 sizes?

Comment: @ForwardEd - 8 maximum different sizes.

Comment: No the size varies depends upon the product.Sometimes 8,sometimes 10.minimum 10 and maximum is 13

Comment: I meant Size 1 | size 2 | ... | Size 5, so 5 columns

Comment: no there are 13 columns like size1,size2....size13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sample data is in A1:G6.

I placed the following in I2 and copied it down to act as an ID counter

```
=I1+(MOD(ROW(A1)-1,COLUMNS(B1:F1))+1=1)
```

After copying it down to the bottom I replaced I2 with 1 so as not to have an error when the cell I1 has header info in it or some other number.

```
=OFFSET($B$2,I2-1,MOD(ROW(A1)-1,COLUMNS($B$1:$F$1)),1,1)
```

I put that in J2 and copied down.  It goes across one cell at a time until it hits the last column then goes back to the first column but down a row.

```
=OFFSET($G$2,I2-1,0,1,1)
```

I placed that in K2 and copied down.  When the product ID number changes to the next value it jumps down to the next row.

Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of concept]

With a small amount of data this method is ok.  However with a large amount of data, OFFSET is a volatile function that will recalculate every time something on the worksheet (potentially workbook) changes.  As such, if this is a one time thing, copy the transformed information when you are done and past it back as values overwriting the formulas.

Functions used in solution:

[MOD](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MOD-function-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3) - Returns the remainder after number is divided by divisor. The result has the same sign as divisor.  This is usually being used as a counter that just continues to loop as you continue through row numbers

[ROW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROW-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d) -  Returns the row number of a reference.  This is being used as a counter above.  As you copy it down the cell reference changes from A1 to A2 to A3 etc. as such the ROW() acts as a counter.

[COLUMNS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COLUMNS-function-4e8e7b4e-e603-43e8-b177-956088fa48ca) - Returns the number of columns in an array or reference.  Note the S on the end.  Similar to ROW or COLUMN in syntax but instead of returning the number of an individual cell, it returns the number of columns in the selection.  In this case I was using it to determine how many times it had to repeat number 1 as this was used as the divisor in the mod function.

[OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) - Returns a reference to a range that is a specified number of rows and columns from a cell or range of cells. The reference that is returned can be a single cell or a range of cells. You can specify the number of rows and the number of columns to be returned.  In the above I locked the reference cell to the top left corner, then using various counters, I moved down or to the right depending on the row, and returned a range of 1 X 1 or a single cell.

Comment: could you please explain me.I have not worked with formulas before.

Comment: does the expanded description and links to how the various function work help?

Comment: .Thaks for you explanation.But I cannot make it .please provide a link for that excel to download